# GroupBy with MinBy including the group key

Tags: c#

I'd like to transform a collection into a mapping from a grouped key to the earliest entry for that group. For example given a list of purchases, I'd like some `IDictionary<Customer, Purchase>`, I can do:

```
purchases.GroupBy(p => p.Customer, (customer, ps) => ps.MinBy(p => p.Date))
```

And this gives me a list of the earliest purchases and I could then transform that with `.ToDictionary`, but is there a better way? Can I replace the `.GroupBy` call with something that gives me the (customer: purchase) mapping directly (since that's what's being calculated anyway).

Comment: `ToDictionary` have [perfect overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-todictionary-3(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-1))-system-func((-0-2)))) for your usecase

Comment: @JL0PD That allows me to convert the already processed list, correct. But I can't move the `MinBy` selection into it, right?